# How to fetch Analytics Data(Clicks,Impressions etc) for my Linkedin UGCPost(Video) Post?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking to find the UgcPosts-Analytics Data(Image attached for the required fields-https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpaZI.png) from the LinkedIn API.I have retrieved UGCPost IDs of all my ugcPosts/Videos from - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/ugc-post-api#get-authors.

UgcPosts are simply the posts that LinkedIn Page Admin/Account owner publishes on his page/account in form of videos.

Now ofcourse there is a Video Analytics API(https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/video-analytics-api) from LinkedIn but this doesn't serve me the fields required as per in my attached image.

The LinkedIn Ads API only fetches Analytics Data for Campaigns by passing their Campaigns_ID. But i am unable to find something for my UgcPosts/Videos.

I want to input UgcPost/Video ID and fetch the metrics as required.

Answer (score 0):

I had been scratching my head about this, too; you actually need to change the second query parameter from `shares` to `ugcpost`. For example, from

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity="+[your_org_ID]+"&shares[0]=[your_share_ID]
```

to

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity="+[your_org_ID]+"&ugcPosts[0]=[ugcPosts_ID]
```

Comment: Please note you should first split share urn and ugc urn 

let q = "";
    for(let f of linkedinResponse.elements) {
        const splits = f.id.split(":");
        if(splits[2] == "ugcPost") {
            q += "&ugcPosts=" + encodeURIComponent(f.id);
        } else if(splits[2] == "share"){
            q += "&shares=" + encodeURIComponent(f.id)};
        }
    }